# How to replace all elements in a list by a single variable

Tags: python, list, replace

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
replace = 1

for x in nums:
    x = replace
    print(x)
```

How can I replace all `nums` to `1`:

`nums = [1,1,1,1,1,1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number (in this case, `1`) is known, just re-assign it like this:

```
replace = 1
nums = [replace]*len(nums)
```

This is way much faster than iteration as suggested in other answers in case of too many numbers.

```
>>> start=time.time(); a = [1 for _ in range(1000000)]; print(time.time() - start)
0.039171695709228516
>>> start=time.time(); a = [1] * 1000000; print(time.time() - start)
0.0036449432373046875
```

Comment: Don't use this for nested lists tho https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly :-)

Answer (score 2):

`x=replace` replaces the iterator, not the value in the list, so try using  `list` comprehension:

```
nums = [replace for x in nums]
print(nums)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
replace=1
nums=[replace]*len(nums)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a loop, you can do the following:

```
nums=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

replace=1

for i in range(len(nums)):
    nums[i]=replace

>>> print(nums)

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways apart from `nums=[1,1,1,1,1,1]`:

```py
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
replace = 1

for index,_ in enumerate(nums):
    nums[index] = replace
```

Answer (score 1):

let me know if you have other questions.

First Mtd:-

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
replace = 1
nums = list(map(lambda x : replace,nums))
```

second Mtd:-

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
replace = 1
nums = [replace for i in range(len(nums))] 
print(nums)
```

Comment: the second method is highly inadvisable.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the second mtd.